# jQuery checkbox .prop() problem

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a function that worked perfectly well before upgrading to jQuery 1.6.2, but now won't work at all. In the past, the function used **.attr("checked")**, but I've tried switching to **.prop("checked")** instead. I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why I cant get .prop("checked") to return a value.

The function is suposed to hide the actual checkboxes and add or remove a class to the parent **li** based on the state of the checkbox. Two things that worked before, no longer work.

- When the page loads, if a checkbox is set as "checked" in the HTML, the jQuery does not apply the proper class to the parent **li**
- When an item is clicked it does set the underlying checkbox as checked, but when clicked again id does not set is as unchecked.

**HTML**:

```
<ul class="checkboxes">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="boro[]" value="Bronx">Bronx</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="boro[]" value="Brooklyn" checked>Brooklyn</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="boro[]" value="Queens">Queens</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('ul.checkboxes').checkBoxes();

$.fn.checkBoxes=function() {
    $ul=$(this);
    $ul.addClass("checkboxes").find("input:checkbox").hide();
    $ul.find("li").addClass($(this).find("input:checkbox").prop("checked")?"checked":"unchecked").click(function(e) {
     $(this).toggleClass("checked unchecked").find("input:checkbox").att("checked",!$(this).prop("checked"));
    )}
)};
```

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: I don't know if this is just a typo or if it's actually your code, but you're calling `checkBoxes` before it's defined, and your last line of code has `att` instead of `attr`.

Comment: @Jacob - I think that's probably it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors:

1) You need to define your function `checkBoxes` before calling it.

2) Not really an error, but there is no point saying addClass('checkboxes') when you've already added that class in HTML.

3) `$(this).find("input:checkbox").prop("checked")` This will only determine if the first checkbox is checked or not. I'm almost positive you want $(this) to refer to the current checkbox, but it's not in the right scope.

4) You wrote `att` instead of `attr`

5) You have an extra `)` at the end of your function.

Here is code that I believe does what you want:

```
$.fn.checkBoxes = function() {
   $(this)
      .addClass("checkboxes")
      .find("input:checkbox")
      .hide()
      .end() -- revert back to $(this)
      .find("li")
      .each(function(){
         $(this).addClass(
            $(this)
              .find("input:checkbox")
              .prop("checked") ? "checked" : "unchecked"
         );
      })
      .click(function(e) {
         var $cb = $(this)
            .toggleClass("checked unchecked")
            .find("input:checkbox");
         $cb.attr("checked", !$cb.prop("checked"));
      });
};

$('ul.checkboxes').checkBoxes();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cpvQ4/

Answer (score 0):

In case your problem is just the syntax errors in your posted code, try this (syntax errors are corrected):

```
$.fn.checkBoxes=function() {
    $ul=$(this);
    $ul.addClass("checkboxes")
       .find("input:checkbox")
       .hide();
    $ul.find("li")
       .addClass($(this).find("input:checkbox").prop("checked")?"checked":"unchecked")
       .click(function(e) {
            $(this)
                .toggleClass("checked unchecked")
                .find("input:checkbox")
                .attr("checked",!$(this).prop("checked"));
       });
};

$('ul.checkboxes').checkBoxes();
```